# How do I add columns based on subquery counts in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following SQL

```
DECLARE @StatusOK int
DECLARE @StatusFailed int

SELECT @StatusOK = COUNT(Status) FROM tblAuditServiceLog WHERE Status = '1'
SELECT @StatusFailed = COUNT(Status) FROM tblAuditServiceLog WHERE Status = '2'

SELECT CompanyId, MethodCalled, tblSystemCompany.Description, @StatusOK as StatusOK, @StatusFailed as StatusFail
FROM tblAuditServiceLog 
INNER JOIN tblSystemCompany ON tblAuditServiceLog.CompanyId = tblSystemCompany.SystemCompanyId
GROUP BY MyId, MethodCalled, tblSystemCompany.Description
```

This works but the count isn't based on the `CompanyId` (row), its returning the count across the table, so its a bit worthless.

From two tables like this

```
:: tblAuditServiceLog 
| CompanyId | MethodCalled | Status |
| 232       | GetProducts  |    1   |

:: tblSystemCompany
| SystemCompanyId | Description |
| 232             | MyCompany   |
```

Where Status = 1 is OK, 2 is Fail

Ideally I'd get an output like this...

```
| CompanyId | MethodCalled | Description | StatusOK | StatusFail |
| 232       | GetProducts  | MyCompany   |    8     |     2      |
| 236       | GetProducts  | MyCompanyB  |    8     |     2      |
| 256       | GetBrands    | MyCompanyC  |    8     |     2      |
```

I'm considering using cursors and just looping through and dumping into a temp table but I'm assuming there's a more optimal way of doing this.

Any help from some SQL Server geniuses appreciated

The results above are (as per the two Select @ queries) the results of counting all the Status = 1 (status ok) and all the status = 2 (status fail) and not, as it should be, Status = AND CompanyId = 232

So assuming multiple company's are logged doing various calls to the web-service, the count would be based on the total count of "OK Statuses" rather than the count for that company.

Comment: Suggest using table aliases and prefixing each column referenced to reduce confusion and make it more readable. For example, which table does MethodCalled come from? I can't tell.

Comment: Also, can you clarify the requirements? Do you want the count of OK calls to be equal to all OK calls for each MyId regardless of MethodCalled/Description, or only all of the OK calls for that MyId/MethodCalled/Description combination? Can you show the data rows that led to the counts 8 and 2?

Comment: Myid is the company id calling the service. The only thing coming from the joined table is the text name of that company . I'm aiming for there to be distinct rows of companies with the sum of ok ans fails. Ok is status equals 1 fail is 2

Comment: Still a confusing word problem. Do you want exactly one row for each distinct value of MyId in the table? Or might there be multiple rows for a MyId if it had different values for MethodCalled? Again, showing the data that landed you at 8 and 2 (including an example of data that is being ignored) would go a much longer way in describing the problem with yet more English.

Comment: Hopefully made it clearer, to be honest it was a rushed question as my brain was in a hundred places at once and my arse half way out of the seat heading for the car. Its hopefully clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a conditional COUNT.

```
SELECT
     MyId, MethodCalled, Description,
     COUNT(CASE Status WHEN 1 THEN tblAuditServiceLog.MyId END) AS StatusOK, 
     COUNT(CASE Status WHEN 2 THEN tblAuditServiceLog.MyId END) AS StatusFail 
FROM 
    ...
```

- There is an implied ELSE NULL in this CASE
- COUNT ignores NULL
- You may need DISTINCT in the COUNT so (`COUNT(DISTINCT CASE...)` but probably not

Observations:

- Your WHERE is not needed. The "table match condition" is already in the JOIN
- Use aliases and qualify columns

So (assumptions made about MethodCalled and Description columns)

```
SELECT  ASL.CompanyId, 
        ASL.MethodCalled, 
        SI.Description, 
        COUNT(CASE ASL.Status WHEN 1 THEN ASL.CompanyId END) AS StatusOK, 
        COUNT(CASE ASL.Status WHEN 2 THEN ASL.CompanyId END) AS StatusFail

FROM    dbo.tblAuditServiceLog AS ASL INNER JOIN
        dbo.tblSystemCompany AS 
        SI ON ASL.CompanyId = SI.SystemCompanyId

GROUP BY ASL.CompanyId, ASL.MethodCalled, SI.Description
```

Comment: Good stuff; I've stuck and edit in if you want to approve it to make your example code match up with the tables in the question so its clearer to anyone who comes stumbling across this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    MyId, 
    MethodCalled, 
    Description, 
    StatusOK   = SUM(CASE WHEN Status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    StatusFail = SUM(CASE WHEN Status = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM tblAuditServiceLog ...
```

Comment: Almost the same as @gbn 's answer but beaten by a few seconds overall :) thanks though its great to see other ways of doing this stuff. MSSQL is still one of those things I need to better understand after years of wallowing in Postgres & MySQL :D